# clear the data in urtext field after 3 second when press button (action)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have 4 `UITextField` for enter the number in each text field. And I have one `button action`. So when i press my button after some 3 second my all data in all `UITextField` field should clear automatically.

I know : `textfield1.text = ""`

But I don't know how to use `delay` and clear my data in my all `UITextField` field. Please help me out. I am using swift 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set a NSTimer schedule it after 3 seconds and in the action you clear the text.

Answer (score 3):

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    textfield1.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

step 2 :  on Button Click action

```
if (self.timer) {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;

}
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(clearTextField:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Step 3 :

```
- (void) clearTextField :(NSTimer *) timer {

    // Clear textfield
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have many option:

1)

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    textfield1.text = ""
}
```

2) `NSTimer`

3)`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Comment: 1 For ** performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:**